# Need last div full width

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to create a layout with css. Nothing complicated but can't figure out the last bit.

I have two rows and need both to go full width.

Row 1 - Has a div that is centered and 70% wide with more content

Row 2 - Should go full width below row 1

For some reason Row 2 is seems to be inside of the 70% section in row 1.

I know it is something simple, just new to laying out CSS.

CodePen: https://codepen.io/gcollins/pen/eEMKqR

**HTML:**

```
<div id="pp-post-container-{post_id}" class="pp-post-container">
  <!-- Row 1 -->
  <div id="pp-post-main-{post_id}" class="pp-post-main">
    <div id="pp-post-content-{post_id}" class="pp-post-content">
      <div id="pp-post-video-{post_id}" class="pp-post-video"></div>
      <div id="pp-post-left-{post_id}" class="pp-post-left">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
      <div id="pp-post-right-{post_id}" class="pp-post-right">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
      </div>
    <div>
  </div>
  <!-- Row #2 -->    
  <div id="pp-post-testimonials-{post_id}" class="pp-post-testimonials"></div>
<div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.pp-post-container {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow: hidden
}

.pp-post-main {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color:#EAEAEA;
}

.pp-post-content {
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 300px;  
  background-color: red;   
}

.pp-post-video {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100px;
}

.pp-post-left, .pp-post-right {
  background-color:pink;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 49.8%;
}

.pp-post-testimonials {
  background-color: green;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: can you give an image how must be?

Comment: If you go to the code pen link you will see the layout. I need the green box to be on the bottom full width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think maybe you are missing a couple of closing `</div>` tags causing the `<div>`in question to inherit the CSS of its container.

```html
   <div id="pp-post-container-{post_id}" class="pp-post-container">
        <!-- Row 1 -->
        <div id="pp-post-main-{post_id}" class="pp-post-main">
          <div id="pp-post-content-{post_id}" class="pp-post-content">
            <div id="pp-post-video-{post_id}" class="pp-post-video"></div>
            <div id="pp-post-left-{post_id}" class="pp-post-left">
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
            </div>
            <div id="pp-post-right-{post_id}" class="pp-post-right">
              <div></div>
              <div></div>
            </div>
          <div>
        </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <!-- Row #2 -->    
        <div id="pp-post-testimonials-{post_id}" class="pp-post-testimonials"></div>
      <div>
```

Comment: Yup that is it!!, so many div's to look at. Thought I had it right but couldn't figure out why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to take out row two from the parent div "pp-post-container"
Also, you have some unclosed divs.

```
</div>
  </div>
```

https://codepen.io/alexMacra/pen/YxajdP